# What is .psq file

Tags: postgresql

In one of our client systems PostgreSQL is installed and we do find many files with ".psq" format.
What is that extension means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.psq` extension is used neither by PostgreSQL server nor by its core tools. Nor by any other tool in that domain I'm aware of.